# ¿Meter un string a uno nuevo ignorando palabras de otro string en C?

Tags: c

Digamos que tengo cierta cadena llamada cadena[1024], que se ve algo así:

```
char cadena[1024] = "int/0void/0/main/0a/0";
```

Posteriormente, tengo un arreglo bidimensional donde almacené unas palabras

```
char palres[20][10]={ "int", "main", "void" };
```

Digamos que tengo un nuevo string llamado `variables[10][10]` donde quiero almacenar todas las palabras que no estén en palres. En este caso `"a"`.

¿Qué debería hacer o de qué función debería googlear?

Primero usé un ciclo do while donde se sumaban las líneas de la cadena (hasta que x fuera 20 y adentro un

```
            if((strcmp(cadena, palres[x]))==0){
            Break;
             }
             Else{
             strcpy(cadena, palres[x]);
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Nota: te falta un (") en la asignacion de palres.

la logica en si esta bien el proceso te quedaria algo asi:

```
int o = 0;
for(int i=0; i<20 ;i++){
    if(!strcmp(cadena, palres[i])==0){
        strcpy(variables[o],palres[i]);
        o++;
    }
}
```